# Java- Having trouble with the resulting totals

Tags: java

I have to write a java program to print up the receipts, but I'm having trouble with the resulting final values. I don't know where I went wrong.. The total values should be: Room $799.50, Telephone $17.25, Meal $129.50, Tips $74.87, Tax $51.97, and Gross Transaction $1073.08

```
public class Hotel 
{

    //Class constants
    private static final double Room_Rate   = 79.95;
    private static final double Tax_Rate    = 6.5;
    private static final double Telephone   = 5.75;
    private static final double Meal_Cost   = 12.95;
    private static final double Tip_Rate    = 0.075;

    //Instance Variables
    private int noOfNights;
    private int noOfGuests;
    private double amountDue;
    private double meal;
    private double tax;
    private double subtotal;
    private double total;
    private double tip;
    private String roomNumber;
    private static double TotalRoomCharges;
    private static double TotalTelephoneCharges;
    private static double TotalMealCharges;
    private static double TotalTips;
    private static double TotalTax;
    private static double GrossTransaction;


    public Hotel (String room)
    {
        roomNumber = room;
        noOfGuests = 1;
        noOfNights = 1;
    }

    public Hotel (String room, int nights)
    {
        this (room);
        noOfNights = nights;
    }

    public Hotel (String room, int nights, int guest)
    {
        this (room, nights);
        noOfGuests = guest;
    }

    public void addNights (int nights)
    {
        noOfNights = noOfNights + nights;
    }

    public void addGuest (int guests)
    {
        noOfGuests = noOfGuests + guests;
    }

    public void calculate ()
    {
        amountDue = Room_Rate * noOfNights * noOfGuests;
        tax = amountDue * Tax_Rate / 100;
        subtotal = amountDue + tax;
        meal = Meal_Cost * noOfNights *noOfGuests;
        tip = Tip_Rate * (subtotal + meal + Telephone);
        total = subtotal + Telephone + meal + tip;

        TotalRoomCharges = TotalRoomCharges + amountDue;
        TotalTelephoneCharges = TotalTelephoneCharges + Telephone;
        TotalMealCharges = TotalMealCharges + meal;
        TotalTips = TotalTips + tip;
        TotalTax = TotalTax + tax;
        GrossTransaction = GrossTransaction + total;

    }

    public double getAmountDue()
    {
        return amountDue;
    }

    public double getTaxDue()
    {
        return tax;
    }

    public double getSubtotal()
    {
        return subtotal;
    }

    public double getTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }

    public double getTip()
    {
        return tip;
    }

    double getMeal()
    {
        return meal;
    }

    public String getRoomNumber()
    {
        return roomNumber;
    }

    public double getRoomRate()
    {
        return Room_Rate;
    }

    public int getNumberOfNights()
    {
        return noOfNights;
    }

    public int getNumberOfGuests ()
    {
        return noOfGuests;
    }

    public static double getPhoneCharges()
    {
        return Telephone;
    }

    public static double getTaxRate()
    {
        return Tax_Rate;
    }

    public static double getTotalRoomCharges()
    {
        return TotalRoomCharges;
    }

    public static double getTotalTelephoneCharges()
    {
        return TotalTelephoneCharges;
    }

    public static double getTotalMealCharges()
    {
        return TotalMealCharges;
    }

    public static double getTotalTips()
    {
        return TotalTips;
    }

    public static double getTotalTax()
    {
        return TotalTax;
    }

    public static double getGrossTransaction()
    {
        return GrossTransaction;
    }
}

public class TestHotel 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Date d = new Date();
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        //Define customers
        Hotel customer1 = new Hotel ("10 - M", 2, 2);
        customer1.calculate();
        display(customer1, f);

        Hotel customer2 = new Hotel ("12 - B");


        Hotel customer3 = new Hotel ("12 - C", 2);
        customer3.calculate();


        customer2.addNights(1);
        customer2.calculate();
        display(customer2, f);

        customer3.addGuest(1);
        customer3.calculate();
        display(customer3, f);

        display (f);
    }

    static void display (Hotel h, NumberFormat f)
    {
        //Set up and display heading and date for each receipt
        System.out.println("\tThe ABC Cheap Lodging, Inc");
        Date d = new Date (); 
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        System.out.println("\tDate: \t" + df.format(d));

        //Display expenses line by line including subtotal
        System.out.println("Room # \t\t" + h.getRoomNumber());
        System.out.println("Room Rate: \t" + f.format(h.getRoomRate()));
        System.out.println("Length of Stay:\t" + h.getNumberOfNights() + " Night(s)");
        System.out.println("No. of Guests: \t" + h.getNumberOfGuests());
        System.out.println("Room Cost: \t" + f.format(h.getAmountDue()));
        System.out.println("Tax:" + h.getTaxRate() + "%\t" + f.format(h.getTaxDue()));
        System.out.println("\tSubtotal \t" + f.format(h.getSubtotal()));
        System.out.println("Telephone \t" + f.format(h.getPhoneCharges()));
        System.out.println("Meal Charges \t" + f.format(h.getMeal()));
        System.out.println("Tip \t\t" + f.format(h.getTip()));

        //Display to total
        System.out.println("\nTOTAL AMOUNT DUE\t.........." + f.format(h.getTotal()));

        //Display thank you message
        System.out.println("\nThanks for staying at The ABC Cheap Lodging, Inc");
        System.out.println("\tPlease come again !!!");
        System.out.println("\n");

    }
    static void display (NumberFormat f)
    {
        System.out.println("\t\t Official Use Only");
        System.out.println("\t\t Today's Summary");
        System.out.println("\tRoom      ....." + f.format(Hotel.getTotalRoomCharges()));
        System.out.println("\tTelephone ....." + f.format (Hotel.getTotalTelephoneCharges()));
        System.out.println("\tMeal      ....." + f.format (Hotel.getTotalMealCharges()));
        System.out.println("\tTips      ....." + f.format (Hotel.getTotalTips()));
        System.out.println("\tTax       ....." + f.format (Hotel.getTotalTax()));
        System.out.println("\t------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("\tGross Transaction .." + f.format (Hotel.getGrossTransaction()));
        System.out.println("Process completed.");
    } 
}
```

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please have a look at: [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: Do not use doubles to represent monetary amounts. Instead, use a long int to keep track ov the number of pennies. Otherwise you will have a lot of trouble with rounding and truncation.

Comment: I'd suggest going the hard way next time and start reading your code carefully and get familiar with debugging in order to be able to track down bugs on your own. Additionally when reading lines like `Hotel customer1 = new Hotel(...)` you should consider different class and variable names. Using static fields for calculating totals also is not how it should be done. If you have just begun programming in Java take your time, it will get better the more you learn and practice. :-)

Comment: @MarkusBenko Thanks for the advice. I've been told not to use static fields for calculating but my prof is insisting. It has been getting easier, but since I have no programming background at all, it's a miracle I've gotten this far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `customer3.calculate()` twice. Remove the first call and you get the expected values.

Comment: Ugh, I didn't see that! Thank you!!!